# Content search web part - list subsite and its logo is vanished

Tags: site-collection, content-search-web-part

I have created Content search web part with the help of MVP Benjamin Niaulin's  [En-Sharegate Blog](http://en.share-gate.com/blog/roll-up-sharepoint-2013-sites-using-search) and i displayed all the sub sites in my site collection, on my site's home page.
But when I see this web part, am not able to see the logo of the sub sites.
Its disappeared. Has anyone faced this issue? How to resolve this?

[image: subsite-logo-is-missing]

my editwebpart--managed property of cswp :

[image: sitelogo-property-cswp]

Update: After full crawl I came to know,managed & crawl properties were not generated in the search schema of my search service application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapping of the properties in the Content Search Webpart(CSWP) are probaly wrong. The CSWP uses a display template to show the results in a specific way. You can choose which display template you want to use in the webpart properties.

You need to do three steps to set/check the right webpart properties.

1. Re-select the current display template item. (It will refresh the settings if you re-select it)
2. Check the box for changing the property mappings
3. Set the `Image-URL` (Afbeeldings-URL in dutch) to `SiteLogo`. This managed property holds the url to the logo of your subwebs.

[image]

After you press 'Ok' the logo's of your subwebs should show in the CSWP. My example now looks like the image below. I have one subsite with a logo.

[image]

Keep in mind that you need to start a crawl of the Search Service Application, if you change a logo on a subsite, before the result will show in the CSWP.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have already selected the correct dropdown item `sitelogo` as  picture url managed property in my right pane[properties of  cswp ].

Comment: Okay that is strange. Are you on a on-premises environment or online environment? Perhaps somehting went wrong with last search crawl? If you are on a on-premises environment you could try to start a new crawl and see if that helps.

Comment: yes, am on on-premises, i started with full crawl after creating my content typesand site columns and i did the incremental crawl as well. is there any version  of SP 2013 will throw this kind of issues ?

Comment: this is my version of my SP: get-spfarm | select BuildVersion

BuildVersion                                                                                                                                                                         
------------                                                                                                                                                                         
15.0.4420.1017.  I will start a New Crawl and update here

Comment: Great! Something in the previous crawl probally went wrong! Sometime just re-crawling helps out! :)